# PowerShell Split after Pipe

Tags: powershell, split, path

I use the following line in my script to return all the paths of all folders at the `$folder` location.

```
dir -recurse $folder|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

This works. But: I only need the fourth element of each path.

I've tried adding `|{$_.Split("\")}[3]}`with the `[3]` in various places but I am getting an error with the split command, that `Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.`

I've tried putting brackets around various sections, and putting the whole expression into brackets and into a split but I can't seem to find a way to attach the split to any part of the pipe... Is there another way, perhaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to put your code within the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse $folder|
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}|
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    ForEach-Object {            
        $_.Split("\")[3]        
    }
```

Comment: is there a slicker way to do this if you know that only one object is going through the pipe? Or do you always have to use foreach?

Comment: @MaxCascone If you don't care about the property heading, you can do it like this: `et-ChildItem -recurse $folder|   Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}| Select-Object {$_.FullName.Split("\")[3]} `

Comment: that's good too, although i kind of forgot why i came here in the first place, which was looking for a more "correct" way to do `(some function).split('')` . Which, actually might be the best way if you are sure there will only ever be 1 object coming out. That might not even be a requirement. I just felt the parentheses were 'messy', although the pipe-select-foreach pattern might be messier. This is an example of style over function.